# Using test rules for JUnit3 TestCase

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit3

First of all let me explain the test setup,

I work for this very large project which has many smaller modules. And to test, we use JUnit in two ways,

- JUnit 4: With @Test annotation and we use a custom test runner that derives from BlockJunit4ClassRunner
- JUnit 3: We a large chunk of tests those are dynamically created from XML files and are based on junit.framework.TestCase. We have a custom test runner for this too that inherits org.junit.runners.AllTests.

For some cross cutting non-functional requirements we have implemented some rules (org.junit.rules) which we use through annotating the test class using @Rule. This works well for JUnit4 but not JUnit3.

Is there a straight forward way of implementing it without making too many changes?

In case of BlockJunit4ClassRunner we have FrameworkMethod,

```
@Override
protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier     notifier) {  
...
}
```

However in case of AllTests, we don't have,

```
@Override
public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
...
...
}
```

Comment: If your JUnit3 tests are dynamicly created from XML, couldn't you change the code that generates them to generate JUnit4-style tests?